# C++ extern pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, global, extern

So I'm writing a program which has a big class called oglapp, and a whole bunch of other classes using it. What I want to achieve is to have a super-global oglapp* across all my .cpps. My approach is to declare an oglapp* in the main.cpp, which has the entry point (which sets up the pointer and starts running the class), and I have an extern reference at the end of the header file of oglapp. In theory, if I use the oglapp class anywhere in my project I need to include the header for it, which includes the extern, and I'm good. This is sorta what I have:

```
//main.cpp
oglapp* app;
entrypoint(){app=new oglapp(); app->run();}

//oglapp.h
class oglapp { ... }; extern oglapp* app;

//classX.h
#include "oglapp.h"
classX { ... };

//classX.cpp
#include "classX.h"
void classX::somefunction(){app->dosomething();}
```

What I get is a big null reference error. I tried including the oglapp header from the .cpp of classX, also tried putting the extern oglapp* app; to each of the classXs individually, I tried everything I could think of. Also, weirdly enough, I don't get null reference errors in all the classXs. Some of them can use the app without a problem, some of them see it as a null pointer. I've yet to discover what determines if it's working or not.

What am I doing wrong? Also, if it's impossible to declare a single super-global pointer to a class this way, how should I go about doing it?

Comment: there is no garantee that your entrypoint function is called at the point where some code in your class files is running. All these extern stuff is really unnecessary evil

Comment: C++ doesn't have "null reference errors". Are you sure you're not trying to run this in Java? :P

Comment: null reference or null pointer who cares it crashes.

Comment: no, I'm debugging c++ in visual studio, and when I call app->dosomething() app is a null pointer

Comment: You could compare the value of `&app` in the Watch window to see if  they're really using the same variable. And make sure that you're not overwriting `app` by overstepping the boundaries of other globals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'll work reliably for anything that is instantiated from within `main` or anything that `main` invokes. For objects at global scope, those are constructed before `main` is run, so your pointer won't be set yet.

You can make everything get initialised from within `main` or higher up the call stack, or you can make an `oglapp` singleton.

Or, since it doesn't look like `oglapp` takes any arguments to its constructor, you can `extern` an actual instance and create one of *those* at global scope, rather than a pointer. Then you have to be wary of the *static initialisation order fiasco* (look it up!), but at least your other global objects will have a *chance*… if you're careful.

Comment: actually everything is invoked from the app. the entry point literally only has app = new oglapp(); app->run(); everything that runs is called from the run(), and when run() runs the pointer should already be set

Comment: Lol, okay thats sorta what was wrong, only I was stupid and didn't realize it. I shortened the entrypoint for app = (new oglapp())->run(); and it ran the constructor, didn't put the pointer in app, tried to to do run() and I guess it would have put the pointer in app after that, only run() crashed. Separated it as app = new oglapp(); app->run(); and works :)

Comment: @CivDav: Yeah :P How come `oglapp::run` doesn't return `void`?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to see where the problem is since you haven't posted all of your code. However, you can avoid the null reference problem by making `oglapp` a singleton. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern for details.

Comment: unfortunately I can't post my whole code, cause it's about a million lines. It's a program I've been developing for a while, I'm just refactoring it right now, and one of the changes I'm doing is having a global oglapp*, instead of storing the same pointer to the same app in each of the objects

Comment: @CivDav, makes sense. It also makes sense for you to make `oglapp` a singleton in this process.

Comment: I am sure you can minimize it in a smaller thing that has the same problem

Comment: yea, I might just rewrite it to a singleton, I wanted it as a global cause I have to call on it like a billion times, so it'd be nice if it were only 3 letters, but if it can't be done this way then i guess a singleton is the way to go

Comment: @CivDav, having `app` as a global variable seems to be brittle in your program. You can create a wrapper function around the global object and use the function instead. i.e. use `app()->...` instead of `app->...`.

Answer (score 0):

"Singeton" seems the most-logical answer here to me.  And it's easy to do.  You simply declare a function that returns an instance of oglapp ... creating it the first time, returning it thereafter.  Something like:

```
static *oglapp _instance = NULL;
*oglapp oglapp_factory() 
{
   if (_instance == NULL) _instance = new oglapp();
   return _instance;
}
```

Your "extern" file declares both the class-definition and *(the external existence of ...)* "oglapp_factory()."  Any routine that needs to interact with the *(one and only)* instance of the class, calls the factory routine to get it.